# Dropbox Core API Python version

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to develop a small personalized app for syncing my personal data with Dropbox using Python. Which Python version does Dropbox Core API requires? Is Python 3 an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropbox Python SDK is built for Python 2.7.

Comment: If there's demand for Python 3 it wouldn't be too much work to prepare a version that works with that. Most of the groundwork was done years ago, but it was never quite finished.